# Order by Specific id first then By rest

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider a Sample Table with two Column RoleId and User Name

```
Role | Name
  1      AB
  3      A
  1      ABC
  2      D
  2      B
  3      Abb
  1      E
  4      TE
```

How can i use SQL queries to get following Output.

```
Role | Name
  3      A
  3      Abb
  1      AB
  1      ABC
  1      E
  2      B
  2      D
  4      TE
```

I just want to Order by Role Id 3 first then by remaining Roleid.
Currently i am using Union to achieve so //

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * From @temp 
         Where roleid=3
UNION ALL
SELECT * From @temp 
         Where roleid != 3
 ) as X
```

Comment: You are generating this by your query, so what's the matter?

Comment: @AlirezaMirzaeiyan - A `union` doesn't provide any guarantee of order.

Comment: Does `Name` participate in the order? Both your explanation and sample data indicate that you only care about `Role`. All of the _current_ answers incorrectly include `Name` in the `order by` clause.

Comment: @HABO yes it Does, when you see my sample result it is sorted alphabetically. within their role group

Comment: `2, D` is followed by `2, B` in your sample results. Which alphabet are you sorting by?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use case to make more complex ordering:

```
select *
 from @temp
 order by case when Role = 3 then 0 else 1 end, Role, Name
```

Comment: This gets you all "3s" in alphabetical order, then all "not 3s" in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from @temp
order by CASE WHEN Role = 3 THEN 0 ELSE Role END, Name
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually use NULLIF, but case might be faster?

```
SELECT   *
FROM     @temp
ORDER BY NULLIF(Role,3), Name
```