# Doctrine ORM - How to choose the first selected item in select query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 4 with EasyAdmin and I need to make a select query that retrieve all the users, but I want the connected user to be selected as the first result.

I don't know how to proceed at all. I was thinking maybe do multiple select in the same query ? but I don't even know how to do this.

So far I have this :

```
   $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
   $authUser = $this->getUser();
   $queryBuilder = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u');
   return $queryBuilder;
```

// Doctrine createQueryBuilder looks like this

```
  public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
        {
            return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()->select($alias)->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy);
        }
```

**EDIT : I imperatively need to return the queryBuilder object, not the result set, that's why it's tricky.**

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615027/order-by-specific-id-first-then-by-rest/34615170 
Either use CASE or UNION.

Comment: Do you have a property in your db that denotes whether someone is connected or not? If so, you could just and an "order by" option to your query builder.

Comment: @ehymel I need to compare the email of the authenticated user to the user that has this email in th db

Comment: In that case you won't be able to get your answer through sql/doctrine alone. You'll have to do a custom sort post-retrieval in your controller, perhaps with php's [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach that will *query all users*, but gives you an array in the order you describe:

```
$users = $userRepository->findall();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $this->getUser() == $user ? $currentUser[] = $user : $otherUsers[] = $user;
}
$myUserList = array_merge($currentUser, $otherUsers);
```

Two sidenotes: **1:** This queries all users and then splits them. I'm not sure if this could be what you want. **2:** if no user is currently logged in this code will not work because `$currentUser` won't be defined. Of course, you can change it so it will also work when no user is logged in.

**Edit based on the fact that returning the querybuilder is imperative:**

You can use `CASE` to test and create a property, which you can hide with `AS HIDDEN` in your query and then order by this hidden property like so:

```
public function currentUserFirst($userId){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, CASE WHEN u.id = :userId THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HIDDEN order')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i edited the post, to precise that i need to return the queryBuilder object, not the result set directly, but i'm not allowed to modify the results of the queryBuilder sadly.

Comment: @naspy971, I kind of thought this was the case. A bit tricky indeed, but possible.

Comment: That works ! wow my knowledge of SQL was limited by this one, many thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

As the first comment pointed out, you will need to use a UNION, which is not supported in DQL.

Therefore your only option is to use a native query using the `Connection` which you need to get from the `EntityManager`.

It would look something like this:

```
$id = $this->getUser()->getId();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id UNION SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE`id` != :id'
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, compact('id'));
```

Comment: thanks, but i edited the post, to precise that i need to return the queryBuilder object, not the result set directly, but i'm not allowed to modify the results of the queryBuilder sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMaxResults:

```
    $qb->andWhere('q.start <= :start')
        ->setParameter(':start', $value)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
    ;
```